# Implicit derivative of $x^y$

Tags: derivatives

So I have a problem that I can't solve for a couple hours now. Can anyone help me understand how to do an implicit derivative of $x^y$.

Thank you very much

Comment: Am I wrong or you need an equation to derive implicitely?

Comment: This is not something you can differentiate yet. Did you mean $x^y = 0$?

Comment: Do you want the derivative with respect to $x$ or $y$?

Comment: Use the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want $\frac d{dx}x^y$, you write it using an exponential and use the chain rule
$$\begin {align}\frac d{dx}x^y&=\frac d{dx}e^{y \ln x}\\&=e^{y \ln x}\frac d{dx}(y \ln x)\\&=e^{y \ln x}\left(\frac {dy}{dx}\ln x+\frac yx\right)\\&=x^y\left(\frac {dy}{dx}\ln x+\frac yx\right)\end {align}$$

Comment: Assuming that $y$ is a function of $x$, could you double-check $\frac{d}{dx}(y\ln x)$?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales:  yes, I got the chain rule right and messed up the product rule later.  Two terms were wrong.  Thanks

Comment: I've been there. Another cup of coffee is the usual cure. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=x^{y(x)}.$ We wish to find $f'(x).$ We employ the usual trick of logarithmic differentiation:
\begin{align*}
\ln(f(x))&=y(x)\ln(x) \\
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}&=y'(x)\ln(x)+\frac{y(x)}{x} \\
f'(x)&=x^{y(x)}\left(y'(x)\ln(x)+\frac{y(x)}{x}\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: So if $y(x) = 1$, then

$$
\frac{d}{dx}x^1 = 0?
$$

Comment: Hang on, I think I've got something wrong...

Comment: There we go, that's fixed it.